# how is this 'search' statement working?

Tags: javascript

I was reading a book and I am not able to find how this `search:` is working.

```
   search:while (true){
    n++;
    for(let i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++){
        if(n%i===0){
            continue search;
        }
    }
```

Is it predefined in javascript, or what is it?

Comment: It looks like this code-sample is cut off.  The `while` loop probably includes a `break` statement or other exit condition below that last curly brace `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a label, and continue tells the loop to go back to the label.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue#Using_continue_with_a_label